# Notation of author-defined functions.

Tags: functions, notation

I have seen functions defined various ways, and I'm wondering which form I should use for some functions. I am hoping to learn what it might be read as, interpreted, etc.

The most common definition of a function is by far $f(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$, for example, $f(a,b,c)=\frac{a^b-c^a}{abc}$. I assume that this is read as "(the) $f$ of $a,b, $ and $c$".

I have seen another definition as $R_z$, for example, $C_n$ is the cyclic graph with $n$ vertices. I have interpreted this to refer to some special element of a larger set, as opposed to $f(x)$, which to me connotes a routine of sorts.

A symbol is often used to denote some function, for example, $\bigcup_{\{x_i\}_{i\in I }}$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and $\sum_{i=0}^{12}i^2-i$. I'm not entirely sure when to use this.

The last definition I have seen is $f(x;y)$. I have seen this only in some probability functions, and, with my limited exposure, I interpreted it to mean "$f$ of $x$ with respect to $y$" or something similar.

My question is this: When should I use each notation? Are there any other ways of denoting a function? I wish to define a large number of functions, and I wonder which cases would require each notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $f(x)$ is the clearest and probably the easiest way of denoting functions. Things like $f(x;y)$ are sometimes used to denote a function of $x$ with a "parameter" $y$ considered *fixed* - we make an implicit mental distinction between the "input" $x$ and the parameter e.g. Suppose you have a function $f(x;\epsilon)=x^2+\epsilon$ with a parameter $\epsilon$; this can be thought of as a whole collection of functions of $x$ which vary with $\epsilon$. And this might be a useful idea, because you see by making $\epsilon$ slightly less than zero you obtain two distinct real roots, when it's zero you have a single root, and for positive $\epsilon$ you have no real roots - so the functions $f(x;\epsilon)$ have *very* different overall properties depending on the value of the parameter.

Often, if your domain of the function is $\mathbb{N}$ it is commonplace to denote $f(n)$ by $A_n$ where $A_n$ takes values in whatever your codomain is.

So overall it's a *conceptual* distinction as to how the values of the function change depending on changes in each of the inputs. Most often, though, you will probably end up using some variant on $f(x)$, incorporating various parameters as needed.

Comment: He's saying that because I told him to. He is also mine

Comment: And to encourage my property, I will vote his question up.